# Getting a blank screen while trying to add a popup to my WordPress website using Elementor Pro

Tags: wordpress, popup, elementor, listings

I am an .net developer and never used or worked on WordPress. I've been trying to add an popup but stuck on this screen. I am using Elementor Pro in my listing theme. The screen I am getting:

[image: Elementor's Edit Screen]

I've been trying to add an popup but stuck on this screen. I am using Elementor Pro in my listing theme. There is not option to add any widget over here.

Comment: Seems like a theme / theme template issue. Try switching to a different theme and check again. Also, are you seeing any error messages on your browser console?

Comment: Getting following two error:

[1] Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token (at ?post_type=elementor_library&p=104732&elementor-preview=104732&ver=1673933899:679:1)
?post_type=elementor_library&p=104732&elementor-preview=104732&ver=1673933899:1368          



[2]GET https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id=GTM-TWPK54D net::ERR_ABORTED 404